# Send large files throug http with httpie

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httprequest, httpie

I recently discovered `httpie` (https://httpie.org) and liked it a lot. it's very simple to make requests for a remote server, specially when working with REST API requests.

But now I'm stucked with sending large files with `httpie`.

It first load the entire file to memory so if file is too large, I get Memory Error:

> http: error: Memory Error:

The command that generates this error is:

```
$ http -f POST www.example.com/upload/ field@file.raw
```

So anyone knows if there is a way to send large files in chunks with `httpie`?

At least in official documentation I didn't found anything.

Comment: Hi @caco, It's a planned feature: https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie/issues/452

Comment: Thanks @jkbrzt. That feature would keep the problem of uploading large files solved at the own `httpie`. Can you give us an approximate date when the feature will be implemented? You can count on me for testing that. And in coding too.